# Unable to build pygobject with jhbuild

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, gtk

I was trying to build `gtk+` and `pygobject` with `jhbuild` (on ubuntu 11.04), but it gives the following error while building `gnome-doc-utils` :

```
checking whether /opt/tarball-gnome2/bin/python version >= 2.4...
configure: error: too old
** Error during phase configure of gnome-doc-utils: ########## Error running ./autogen.sh --prefix /opt/tarball-gnome2 --libdir '/opt/tarball-gnome2/lib'  --disable-static --disable-gtk-doc  *** [8/8]
```

Comment: Why is it picking up python from `/opt/tarball-gnome2/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the `jhbuild` [installation](http://live.gnome.org/Jhbuild) manual, it should check whether you already have the `gnome-common`, `gnome-doc-utils` and `autotools` programs already installed, and if not it will use the `Makefile` approach.

I would suggest that you will install the above packages with `apt-get install` first, then try to run the `./autogen.sh` command again.

I am assuming that you are using [this](http://live.gnome.org/Jhbuild) official guide on how to install it.